# Timeout alternative in .NET 6 using WaitAsync

Tags: c#, timeout, task, .net-6.0

I'm trying to translate the following timeout code to .NET 6's `WaitAsync`.

```cs
using (var delayCts = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    var resultTask = await Task.WhenAny(sending, Task.Delay(5000, delayCts.Token));

    if (resultTask != sending)
    {
        _webSocket.Abort();
    }
    else
    {
        delayCts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

I think that's the opposite is supposed to be:

```cs
try
{
    await sending.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    _webSocket.Abort();
}
```

The question is are there any differences that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Looks about right. I’m interested in why you cancel the delay task in the first example?

Comment: LGTM. The original code has a bug where the CTS could be disposed while still being used.

Comment: @StephenCleary, it is from SignalR's implementation https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Http.Connections.Client/src/Internal/WebSocketsTransport.cs#L216-L232

Comment: @stuartd delays that are not "needed" any more should be cancelled to avoid timer leaking

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit, why would they leak a timer though?

Comment: @stuartd if the task has finished before the delay's timer has elapsed - the timer stays alive until it's elapsed. It's not a big deal, but in a high-thruput code can become a problem. Just to be clear `WaitAsync` does that for you. but if you're using the "old" way, like in the OP's first example - then cancel it. https://andrewlock.net/just-because-you-stopped-waiting-for-it-doesnt-mean-the-task-stopped-running/

Comment: Thanks @AlexfromJitbit that's a great link, which is making me think again about some of my code.

Comment: For anyone interested - _The TimerQueueTimer instances - (created by Task.Delay) will be cleaned up when the Task.Delay() call expires, but if you're creating Task.Delay() calls faster than they're ending, then you will have a memory leak._